# MiniProfiler WCF Async Support

Tags: wcf, asynchronous, mvc-mini-profiler

Does MiniProfiler.WCF support asynchronous calls of WCF?

It seems that when calling our WCF service using our async interface `AfterReceiveRequest` on `IDispatchMessageInspector` is never triggered.

I believe this is due to the face that Async is not implemented in the whole WCF pipeline only at the operation level.

This led me to write a `IParameterInspector` and to start profiling in `BeforeCall` and `AfterCall` using `OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders` and `OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders` to read and write the headers. This works fine on the host but on the client there will not be a `OperationContext.Current` so we cannot receive the headers.

`AfterReceiveReply` on the Client inspector is never triggered by async WCF so we can not get the headers from there either.

Has anyone made any progress in this area or does anyone have any advice about how we can get the timings back on the client?